# Joining together 2 converted text fields

Tags: sql, join, text, concatenation, sql-convert

Struggling to join two text fields

```
,RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(IM.ITEMDESC,',',''))) AS ITEMDESCR
,RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(convert(varchar(MAX),[TXTFIELD]), 
CHAR(13),' '),',',''),''))) AS EXTRADESCRIPTION
```

Had to remove the carriage return on the second line - Have tried Concat and + but neither are working. Also have null values in the second line therefore if null value want to display the first line only.

Comment: SQL Server or mysql?

Comment: SQL Server . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
create table im (id int not null identity(1,1), itemdesc varchar(64), txtfield text)
insert into im values 
 ('Pencil','Writing utensil')
,('Pen',null)
,(null,'Writing utensil')

select
    rtrim(ltrim(replace(im.itemdesc,',',''))) as itemdescr 
  , rtrim(ltrim(isnull(replace(replace(convert(varchar(max),txtfield), char(13),' '),',',''),''))) as extradescription
  , isnull(rtrim(ltrim(replace(im.itemdesc,',','')))+' ','')
  + isnull(rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(convert(varchar(max),txtfield), char(13),' '),',',''))),'')
    as combined_description
from im
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YQDARN44856

returns:

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------------+
| itemdescr | extradescription |  combined_description  |
+-----------+------------------+------------------------+
| Pencil    | Writing utensil  | Pencil Writing utensil |
| Pen       |                  | Pen                    |
| NULL      | Writing utensil  | Writing utensil        |
+-----------+------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: thank you                                                                                                 
, isnull(rtrim(ltrim(replace(im.itemdesc,',','')))+' ','')
 + isnull(rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(convert(varchar(max),txtfield), char(13),' '),',',''))),'')
  as combined_description   

Worked great :)